# How to modify path width?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, line-art

I have this image of a heart:

[favorite.svg](http://www.kirkouimet.com/files/images/favorite.svg)

and this image of a back arrow:

[back.svg](http://www.kirkouimet.com/files/images/back.svg)

I would like to modify the line width of the back arrow to match the line width of the heart. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this in illustrator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the artwork was just a stroked path, @Scott would be right. But from what I can see when I look at the SVG files, they are filled shapes:

`See the nodes in the corners?`
[image: See the nodes in the corners?]

`So you will need to Offset the path by a negative amount:`

`Object -> Path -> Offset Path`
[image]

`To end up with a thin arrow`
[image]

Or, just scale down the arrow until it has the appearance of line thickness that you like, but it won't be at the original size anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Set the stroke weight on both paths to the same value using the **Stroke Panel**.